# Unity 3d - CLOTH Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cannot find the cloth object in CreateObject > 3d in  my unity 3d personal edition. Theres no cloth object everywhere.. how can i fix this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add Component` -> Search for `Cloth` or `Interactive Cloth`
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cloth.html

[image]

Comment: Thankyou... i got it now. I have another problem. cloth is not colliding in my capsule object even I set it to collide in the capsule..

Comment: In that case, you should mark the answer as accepted & open a new question. I can't answer your `another question`, but the community can.